# Filter a table by month in Delphi xe3

Tags: delphi, ms-access, delphi-xe3

Im using Access as database:

I have table named FS and a date field named DateTime which contains records as mm/dd/yyyy

How do I filter the DateTime field by month only.

Answer (score 0):

Figure it out:

1. In the Access database changed the field DateTime to string.
2. In Delphi applied filter like:

   `FStable.Filter := 'DateTime LIKE '+ QuotedStr('comboBox1.Text'+'%');`

For some reason Filter does not work on datetime fields.

That was my problem.